# Как восстановить keystore.debug.lock

Tags: android, lock, keystore

Я по ошибке удалил из директории .android на диске C файл  keystore.debug.lock (не уверен в точности названия), из-за чего мой проект перестал собираться (в частности, жалуется на то, что не существует файла, который он видел до этого)

Можно ли его как-то пересоздать? Либо взять из других проектов?

Comment: Файл `debug.keystore.lock` это lock-файл, в нем нет содержимого, он пустой. Он создается для блокировки какого-то процесса, предполагаю, чтобы два разных процесса не писали в один и тот же файл `debug.keystore`. Если хотите по какой-то причине восстановить `debug.keystore.lock` файл, то просто создайте пустой файл в домашней директории в `.android/debug.keystore.lock`. Но скорей всего вам нужно восстановить какой-то другой файл, приведите полный текст ошибки (добавьте его [в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1521562/edit)).

Comment: Сомневаюсь что проблема в этом файле. Вы можете вообще удалить всю директорию `.android` и при первой необходимости она будет создана заново. Только у вас тогда сменится дебажный ключ и следующая дебаг-сборка будет устанавливаться только через удаление установленной ранее вместе с данными. Эмуляторам это не грозит, так как их придётся заново создавать/настраивать.